# Unable to instantiate bean

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to implement a simple web service using spring. Following bean declaration has been added to app-ctx.xml:

```
   <bean class="com.user.services.MessageService_BindingImpl" scope="request"/>
```

Everything works perfectly. After that i decide to try to use injection through a constructor - i've added a simple constructor with one argument (String type) and i've modified bean confoguration:

```
  <bean class="com.user.services.MessageService_BindingImpl" scope="request">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Hello world"/></bean>
```

And after that i got following exception:

> java.lang.InstantiationException: com.user.services.MessageService_BindingImpl

Looks like there is something with my constructor. After adding default non-arg constructor, exception disappears. How to use overloaded constructor? Thanks.

MessageService_BindingImpl -

```
public class MessageService_BindingImpl implements com.user.service.MessageService_PortType {

   public MessageService_BindingImpl (String hello) {
   }

   public ReadMessagesResponse readMessages(ReadMessagesRequest readMessagesRequest) throws RemoteException {
      MessageService mService = new MessageService();
      return mService.readmessages();
   }
}
```

Comment: Let's see your `MessageService_BindingImpl` class.

Comment: Also, can you post the full exception?

Comment: Not sure - this is exactly what i am getting as soap response. There is nothing in server/app log files...

Comment: Your second `<bean>` definition would not throw any instantiation exceptions as it stands. You must not be showing us something.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your question.

Are you asking why

```
<bean class="com.user.services.MessageService_BindingImpl" scope="request"/>
```

is failing with a class like

```
public class MessageService_BindingImpl implements com.user.service.MessageService_PortType {

   public MessageService_BindingImpl (String hello) {
   }

   ...
}
```

?

If so, then the answer is that by not providing any `constructor-arg`, Spring will try to use your class' no-argument constructor. Since you don't have one, it can't use it.

Comment: Maybe (thanks to my language skills :-). First bean definition related to a class without any constructor. After adding constructor-arg attribute, the class has been modified by overloading the default constructor (with string-type argument).

Comment: @psed In Java, if you don't provide any constructor for your class, the compiler adds a default no-arg constructor. If you do provide a constructor, the compiler does nothing. If you only have one constructor, there is no overloading going on.